# Pymongo only returning id field when empty object is passed

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have working with python and MongoDB.  To connect to mongo I am using python module Pymongo.  As I can see from documentation which is very abstract and small.  It seems most of the things works as it works in normal MongoDB collection. But there is a strange part related to find query.

**In Mongo Shell:**

```
 db.my_collection.find({}, {})
 Results Array Fields:  { _id, field1, field1, field3 ..... etc} 
 //Notice:  Returning all Fields of each Document
```

**In Python Shell:**

```
 pymonogoMongoClient("localhost", 27017)['DB']['my_collection'].find({}, {})
 Results Array Fields:  {_id} 
 Notice  // Only Id is returning for all Docs
```

I understand that I get my desired results by not specifying empty {} in second argument of find but that is not what my code design allow. I am creating a kind of ORM for my Flask Application where I have to write generic Database function. And it is not allow.

Any help or get around to get all the Documents by passing an argument will be appreciated.   Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post an example doc?

Comment: @laike9m it should be reproducible without needing to see one of their documents, and it "is" reproducible. The real question is why would you just simply not pass in the projection when you know there is no keys within the dict? Is the question instead, "How to conditionally add a Projection?"

Comment: Personally I would make a list of arguments dynamically and then pass them in with `find(*find_args)`. In that way you can dynamically add the query, projection and any supported option of `find()` as you please. If I were writing an ODM that was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html) here is why that happens:

> projection (optional): a list of field names that should be returned
>   in the result set or a dict specifying the fields to include or
>   exclude. If projection is a list “_id” will always be returned. Use a
>   dict to exclude fields from the result (e.g. projection={‘_id’:
>   False}).

What you could do, though, is this:

```
if projection == {}:
    projection = None

pymonogoMongoClient("localhost", 27017)['DB']['my_collection'].find({}, projection)
```

Comment: thanks @dnickless thats what I couldn't understand from docs. Its working fine when passing None.  Thanks